# On my API Voice Recording Project I cannot seem to Fetch request from the browser

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

During fetch request it shows 500 Internal Server Error but the code seem to be right but it does not work. It could be the fact browser has an update and for privacy reasons have blocked fetch request!

```
let mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
      mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", (event) => {
        // record audio data into array
        audioChunks.push(event.data);
      });
      mediaRecorder.addEventListener("stop", () => {
        // Convert audioChunks into audioBlob.
        const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks, { type: 'audio/mpeg' })
        audioChunks.length = 0;

        // append the audioBlob to formData.
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("files", audioBlob);

        // Make fetch request to Rails in order to transcribe.
        const crsfToken = document.querySelector("meta[name='csrf-token']").content;
        fetch("/transcript", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {"X-CSRF-Token": crsfToken},
          body: formData
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(note => {
          imagify(note)
          })
        .then(note => window.location.href = `/notes/`);
      });
,,,
```

Comment: a `500` status indicates the server has an issue - you haven't shown any server code - inspect that request to see everything the server is sending in the response, it may help you find out what you've done wrong

Comment: I have tried asking chatgpt and it gives me this The "Internal Server Error" typically means there is a problem with the server code or configuration. To fix this issue, you'll need to debug the server-side code responsible for handling the "/transcript" endpoint.

Comment: Yes - that's correct

Comment: Any idea how I can debug the server side code? ^^

Comment: I take it the server side code is something called ruby? then, no. Never did Ruby

Comment: Yes the code is in Ruby and JavaScript

Comment: Maybe I think should reach out to API service and inform them about this issue because I believe it’s abit complex to fix

Comment: while the error is a server side error, `this issue` could still be caused by frontside code doing something the server doesn't expect - I've seen it happen very rarely

Comment: But my code seems to be fine and it’s weird like it used to work before and now suddenly stopped working!